# How to set index in DevExpress ComboBoxEdit?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

How to "Set" the `SelectedIndex` in DevExpress `ComboBoxEdit`? 
I tried both in **XAML** and in code behind, but the index was not set, it starts out with a blank item.

**My XAML:** [I can't see why this doesn't work, but it doesn't..]

```
<dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
    <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.Items>
            <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem IsSelected="True">AAA</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
            <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>BBB</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
            <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>CCC</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.Items>
    </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
</dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
```

**My C# code:** 
[I'm getting the **countStr** correctly so I'm sure the `ComboBoxEdit` and the items are initialized and added ok, but `SelectedIndex` still don't set the index..]

* also I do not want to use `EditValue` to set the value, I need to use an integer (**Index**) to set it.

```
private void Foo_LinkControlLoaded(object sender,
    DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.BarItemLinkControlLoadedEventArgs e)
{
    BarEditItemLink link = (BarEditItemLink)sender;
    countStr = ((ComboBoxEdit)link.Editor).Items.Count.ToString();
    ((ComboBoxEdit)link.Editor).SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no SelectedIndex or SelectedItem property within the editor settings (e.g. ComboBoxEditSettings).
But you can set the [SelectedIndex](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsLookUpEditBase_SelectedIndextopic), SelectedItem or EditValue properties of [ComboBoxEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfEditorsComboBoxEdittopic) via the editor style:

```
<dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="beiComboBox">
    <dxb:BarEditItem.EditStyle>
        <Style TargetType="dxe:ComboBoxEdit">
            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
    </dxb:BarEditItem.EditStyle>
    <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
            <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.Items>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>AAA</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>BBB</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>CCC</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
            </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.Items>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
    </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
</dxb:BarEditItem>
```

You can also set a [ComboBoxEdit.SelectedIndex](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsLookUpEditBase_SelectedIndextopic) property from codebehind if you catch the Loaded event:

```
<dxb:BarEditItem.EditStyle>
    <Style TargetType="dxe:ComboBoxEdit">
        <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ComboBoxEdit_Loaded"/>
    </Style>
</dxb:BarEditItem.EditStyle>

//...
void ComboBoxEdit_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ((ComboBoxEdit)sender).SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks. Do you also have a code behind solution? I can't see why my c# codes does not set the SelectedIndex - may be I cannot do that through casting?

Comment: @KMC: I have updated my answer. P.S. I'm not from devexpresss support team, but I'm wotking with their controls from time to time))

Comment: With this (first) solution, EditValueChanged is not raised for this first item. Is there a workaround?